# Are there any dangers in exposing git sha1 commit hashes?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, reverse-engineering

For a non-public repository, are there any potential security concerns in sharing git commit hashes? For example, when I post a git-related stackoverflow question that involves git commits from private repos, I will change the hashes slightly out of paranoia.

Or perhaps a website will serve a git commit hash in a header to show what version of the code the site is running to internal developers.

Continuing the thought, are there any concerns about an attacker getting access to **sequential** sha1 hashes?

Comment: nope, you stalker

Comment: I'm not the one considering exposing my hashes all over the place :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As explained [there](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects), the SHA-1 hashes are identifiers for the stored objects, including commits -- they are computed deterministically from the object contents. There is no secret in there. Though SHA-1 is nominally one-way, this would *theoretically* allow an attacker, who wants to guess the contents of an object, to *verify* whether his guess is correct or not. This would entail guessing *exactly*, down to the last bit, including time stamps and other similar things.

If your object contains some secret data which can be brute-forced (e.g. a password, subject to [dictionary attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_attack)), then an attacker *might* use the SHA-1 hash as a test. This seems hard because of the condition on guessing everything else properly, but the possibility is there. Therefore, **if** your commit contains such secret data, you are right to change the hash value -- but in that case, don't change it *slightly*, because a quasi-match is as good as an exact match on hash values, for the attacker. Change the hash values completely: replace each one of them with a sequence of 40 random hexadecimal characters.

Note that knowing the hash values does not grant any other extra power to the attacker; in particular, they do not give him access to the repository.

Comment: "a quasi-match is as good as an exact match on hash values" .. I don't think this is true. Can you point me to a resource that supports this point?

Answer (score 1):

> For a non-public repository, are there any potential security concerns in sharing git commit hashes?

Most definitely not. There is absolutely no way you can correlate the SHA 1 hash of a git commit to the actual contents of the commit.

> Continuing the thought, are there any concerns about an attacker getting access to sequential sha1 hashes?

What exactly do you mean by sequential SHA 1 hashes?

Comment: let's say I commit, and an attacker knows the exact contents of that commit, and has the sha1. If I commit a password *only* in the next commit, and the attacker gets the sha1 of the next (sequental) commit, how trivial would it be to expose the password?

Comment: @DelvarWorld I do suggest you read up on the properties of a strong hash. What you are suggesting is completely impossible.